# Create a dictionary from text file

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

Alright well I am trying to create a dictionary from a text file so the key is a single lowercase character and each value is a list of the words from the file that start with that letter.

The text file containts one lowercase word per line eg:

```
airport
bathroom
boss
bottle
elephant
```

Output:

```
words = {'a': ['airport'], 'b': ['bathroom', 'boss', 'bottle'], 'e':['elephant']}
```

Havent got alot done really, just confused how I would get the first index from each line and set it as the key and append the values. would really appreatiate if someone can help me get sarted.

```
words = {}

for line in infile:
  line = line.strip() # not sure if this line is correct
```

Comment: Is this homework?  What have you come up with so far?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you include the code you've tried so far in your question so we can see where you need more help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's examine your example:

```
words = {}
for line in infile:
  line = line.strip()
```

This looks good for a beginning. Now you want to do something with the `line`. Probably you'll need the first character, which you can access through `line[0]`:

```
  first = line[0]
```

Then you want to check whether the letter is already in the dict. If not, you can add a new, empty list:

```
  if first not in words:
    words[first] = []
```

Then you can append the word to that list:

```
  words[first].append(line)
```

And you're done!

If the lines are already sorted like in your example file, you can also make use of [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), which is a bit more sophisticated:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

with open('infile.txt', 'r') as f:
  words = { k:map(str.strip, g) for k, g in groupby(f, key=itemgetter(0)) }
```

You can also sort the lines first, which makes this method generally applicable:

```
groupby(sorted(f), ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the responce but i am actully not familiar with this method because we havent learned it. So I am not sure if I can use that.

Comment: I am working on a for loop with what I allready had and some stuff I found. You can try to help me fix that if you dont mind

Comment: @Who: Okay, I added a small walk-through using a simpler method :)

Comment: Thanks alot for the walk-through that helped a lot..that was exactly what I was looking for..gonna give it a try

Answer (score 1):

`defaultdict` from the `collections` module is a good choice for these kind of tasks:

```
>>> import collections
>>> words = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> with open('/tmp/spam.txt') as f:
...   lines = [l.strip() for l in f if l.strip()]
... 
>>> lines
['airport', 'bathroom', 'boss', 'bottle', 'elephant']
>>> for word in lines:
...   words[word[0]].append(word)
... 
>>> print words
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': ['airport'], 'b': ['bathroom', 'boss', 'bottle'], 'e': ['elephant']})
```